# Network manager gone after update

Tags: networking, wireless, updates, network-manager, broadcom

I did a software update on my HP 250 G3, after that the icon of the network manager is gone, connection is gone, if I plug an Ethernet cable in, nothing happens. If I go to settings > network, a pop up shows up

`Network services are not compatible with this version of the system`

OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: Screen of lshw -class network]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command "sudo service network-manager start" . This solved the problem for me.

The error message which is troubling you:

[image]

Command to start network manager:

[image]

And it works finally

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it doesnt, after the command i got this in console "network-manager start/spawned, process 6308" but nothing changed, still doesnt work