# Ububtu 14.04 64 bit Network not working after update

Tags: 14.04, networking

I just updated ubuntu 14.04 on 01-30-16 and now my netwoking is not working. If I go to settings and try to open networking, I get the message "the system network services are not compatible with this version". Any help would be appreciated. I don't want to reinstall if I don't have to.

Comment: There is a possible answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/727626/283721)

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/727462/283721) has also been upvoted several times - seems to be working for people.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/727648/421836 I have previously answered this question. Have a look over it . Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the kind replies. Unfotunately, I didn't see them and impatiently upgraded to 15.04. I do not recommend doing this as I lost all the software I had installed over the last 5 years. My fault. I just got impatient. Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: I understand the frustration and desire to upgrade immediately to solve the problem, but why 15.04?  That goes end of life on Feb 6!

Comment: It was just the closest to what I had that I could readily find. Thought it might be the smoothest. Gotta work on that impatience thing. I thought maybe I wouldn't lose as much too. Hey, live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this method:

1. Open up the terminal and type in:

   ```
   sudo service network-manager stop
   ```
2. Then do:

   ```
   sudo service network-manager start
   ```

This fixed the problem for me. Hope this works for you too :)

Comment: Why not just `restart`?